# Update mysql in php is not working - I suspect variable issues

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I am not able to update a mysql table in php. 
I have 3 files: the first file lists table results with an "update" button linked to the email field in the table. The first file seems to be able to pass the Email field to the second file fine just fine. 
The second file includes a form that contains all the datafields and a submit button. 
The third file includes the update query to the database. The query executes successfully but the number of rows affected is always 0. I suspect the Email address is not being passed, but it's possible that the other variables aren't being passed either. Any recommendations?

first file - I'm only including the php - select the row to update from a table:

```
        require 'project_db.php';
        mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db("$database")or die("cannot select DB");

        //execute the SQL query and return records
        if (!$result = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM $table"))
        echo 'mysql error: ' .mysql_error();

        //fetch tha data from the database
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Website']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Gender']; ?></td>
            <td class="record-edit">
                <form action='edit_form.php?Email="<?php echo $row['Email']; ?>"' method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Email" value="<?php echo $row['Email']; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class="record-delete">
                <form action='project_selectdelete2b.php?Email="<?php echo $row['Email']; ?>"' method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Email" value="<?php echo $row['Email']; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
   <?php }
    ?>
```

The second file is the php form:

```
            $order = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE Email='$Email'";
            $result = mysqli_query($order);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            ?>
            <form id ="edit_my_beach_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='edit_data.php?Email="<?php echo $row['Email']; ?>"' method="post">
            <fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="Email" value="<?php echo "$row[Email]"?>" />
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo"$row[Name]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Website: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Website" value="<?php echo"$row[Website]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Gender" value="<?php echo"$row[Gender]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                ...
                ...
                ...  
                <tr>
                    <td>Comments: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBComment" value="<?php echo"$row[FBComment]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
            </fieldset>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="save" value="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
            </table>
```

And the third file is the update query:

```
      $Email = $_REQUEST["Email"];
      $Name = $_POST['Name'];
      $Website = $_POST['Website'];
      $Gender = $_POST['Gender'];
      $FBCountry = $_POST['FBCountry'];
      $FBCity = $_POST['FBCity'];
      $FBFeature = $_POST['FBFeature'];
      $FBClean = $_POST['FBClean'];
      $FBCrowd = $_POST['FBCrowd'];
      $FBPeople = $_POST['FBPeople'];
      $FBWildlife = $_POST['FBWildlife'];
      $FBBackdrop = $_POST['FBBackdrop'];
      $FBWaves = $_POST['FBWaves'];
      $FBSeabed = $_POST['FBSeabed'];
      $FBTemp = $_POST['FBTemp'];
      $FBAmenities = $_POST['FBAmenities'];
      $FBComment = $_POST['FBComment'];


  //Define the query
  $query = "UPDATE $table
        SET Name = '" .  $Name . "',  Website = '" . $Website . "', Gender = '" . $Gender . "',
            FBCountry = '" . $FBCountry . "', FBCity = '" . $FBCity . "', FBFeature = '" . $FBFeature . "',
            FBClean = '" . $FBClean . "', FBCrowd = '" . $FBCrowd . "', FBPeople = '" . $FBPeople . "',
            FBWildlife = '" . $FBWildlife . "', FBBackdrop = '" . $FBBackdrop . "', FBWaves = '" . $FBWaves . "',
            FBSeabed = '" . $FBSeabed . "', FBTemp = '" . $FBTemp . "', FBAmenities = '" . $FBAmenities . "',
            FBComment = '" . $FBComment . "'
       WHERE Email = '". $_POST['Email'] ."';";


  //sends the query to delete the entry
  $execute = mysqli_query ($connect,$query);

  $rows = mysqli_affected_rows ($connect);


  if ($execute) {
      echo "Successful";
          echo $rows;
          echo $Email;
  }
  else {
      echo 'OOPS, we have a problem!! Check edit_data';
      echo $rows;
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Another fine example of mixing MySQL APIs.

Comment: does your code update the table?

Comment: Print the query string out *after* variable substitution.  If the answer isn't obvious (the problem is obvious about 95% of the time) then edit the question and add the query to the question.

Comment: @Neil, no it does not update it even when it says "Successful" it returns that affected rows = 0

Comment: Have you checked that the table has changed even if it returns 0?

Comment: @TobyAllen, I checked, it doesn't change - the email variable passed is blank

Comment: For the love of god, sanitize user input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're passing the email through the URL which is the GET method. So,

```
$query = "UPDATE $table
   SET Name = '" .  $Name . "', ...
    ...
   WHERE Email = '". $_GET['Email'] ."';";
```

and in your first file, you're using the `mysql` engine

```
mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$database")or die("cannot select DB");
```

n in the third file you're using `mysqli` engine

```
$execute = mysqli_query ($connect,$query);
$rows = mysqli_affected_rows ($connect);
```

Both need to be same. Moreover, I suggest you use Object Oriented style for better code integrity.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Comment: @Gordon I printed the query string and it seems that as I suspected, the Email variable isn't being passed to the third file... but I don't understand where it's missing: UPDATE surveyresults SET Name = 'mm', Website = 'm', Gender = 'm', FBCountry = 'm', FBCity = 'm', FBFeature = 'm', FBClean = 'm', FBCrowd = 'm', FBPeople = 'm', FBWildlife = 'mm', FBBackdrop = 'm', FBWaves = 'm', FBSeabed = 'm', FBTemp = 'm', FBAmenities = 'm', FBComment = 'm' WHERE Email = '';

Comment: Where do I need the GET statement? I tried adding it but it didn't work, I'm not sure where to put it in...

Comment: in your query, you're using `WHERE Email = '". $_POST['Email']`. I think this should be `$_GET`